# How Can I generate a data dictionary which contains the data types of a Json file.

Tags: mongodb

The data dictionary should be generated from a CSV file of sample data.

Comment: You want to get the data types from a json file in the title, but you are talking about CSV in the post? Which one is the case?

Comment: Sorry for the confusing question. What I have is a .CSV sample data but when I save it in Mongodb it will be in JSON format.

Comment: Edit your question with more details as what you have done so far and what exactly you are looing for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not get all the types from a csv or json file.

Lets check the following example:

```
asd;3534;0674;slfo
```

What are the types? The third column with the value `0674` contains a string or an integer, decimal, float or what? Has that leading 0 any meaning? If so, it should be a string/character data.

The case is similar with the JSON files: Dates are stored as strings in those files (for example), you can not determine what its type. There should be values in a sample data which seems to be valid dates, but what is those values are some kind of category identifiers or generated identifiers (2014-01-24 could be for example 'marketing campaign' (id = 01) in the year 2014 for the partner with id of 24).

**Conclusion**: you can get a prediction from sample data, but you have to determine the real type manually (or at least revise the predictions). You have to 'add' the business meaning to the determination process -> you have to know what does that data mean to determine the data type required to store that data.

Also please note, that the [RFC of the CSV](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) files is not determines the "string identifier" character. It could or could not wrap the string with '"' or any other characters.

Comment: Thank you Pred. What I needed is to validate user inputs to MongoDB database and designing a data dictionary seams to be the best option. Is there any other way to achieve this task?

Comment: What kind of validation do you want to do on what kind of user input for what purposes? (Users mostly don't create csv files manually by typing)

Comment: I was working on Mongodb. I uploaded 500 records which was in .csv format to the database. And I do not want others to upload or enter a different type of record or file format to the specific collection. It is a school project which I am planing to add up to it for my final thesis work.

Comment: It was my divisor's idea to design and develop a data dictionary. Any possibility to develop a method of validating user input will do fine.

Comment: OK, so if mongodb is only for storing / for BI purposes, you simply do not want to walidate the input. If the database is a production database used by an application, the application's role to validate the input. In relational databases you have simple tools to force some rules, but the main place where validation occurs is the application.

Comment: Yes, I understand that about mongodb and the other NoSQL databases. But I was experimenting how to make it better before the use of NewSQL consumes the database world.Any way to adjust the input would work for me. Thank you

Comment: Nice question, but this leads to a big and mostly opinion based conversation. Mine in short: NoSQL and NewSQL systems are really fast in certain scenarions, because they are built to solve the problems related to that scenario. In most cases the speed achieved by bypassing some or all validation processes (called constraints in SQL servers). If you want to make them better, your first task is to determine in what. What should the system do better? Do not forget: any kind of modification is mostly a tradeoff: consistency check costs CPU time->implementing one slows down the system.

Comment: Thank you Pred. Let me me check what possibilities I have and I will get back to you.